# Installing an addon

Tags: add-on

There is this addon that was built called Window Generator 2. It can be [found at this BA thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?270422-AddOn-Window-Generator-2). However, when I go to the download link it shows up in a new tab as a bunch of code.

How can I download and use this addon in Blender?

Comment: related when this doesn't work, and why: [install-from-file-not-working-to-install-addon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13899/install-from-file-not-working-to-install-addon?rq=1) and [addons-only-some-zips-will-install](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install/39747#39747)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

1. Download [the script](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23340323/add_Window.py) (Right click on on the link or on the page it is on and choose *Save As...*) and save it with a `.py` extension for example.. `window_gen2.py`.
2. Open *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and under *Add-ons*, click *Install from File*. Then navigate to the file you downloaded and select it.

   [image: Install from file]
3. It should now appear in the window and you can tick the checkbox in the upper right to enable it.

   [image: Enable]

If you would like to have the add-on enabled every time you start Blender, click *Save User Settings* at the bottom.

---

Alternatively, you can just save it and open it in the text editor and press *Run Script*.

Comment: Will the script be copied to a blender-specific location, or will deleting it from, say, one's download folder cause Blender to fail to load it?

Comment: @hexafraction Blender will copy it into its scripts folder, next to where your config is. You can safely delete the file from the download folder.

Comment: this works for zips nowadays too btw

Comment: @ikIsR I have created a small script its running fine in text editor when i saved in .py and install and want to activate the check box i cant find it i search in community, testing and official. This is my small script :      import bpy
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=True)

Comment: @iKlsR I have an addon that requires restarting Blender to start working. I have compiled Blender as a Python module. How can I restart the `bpy` module? Is that even possible?

Comment: @Amir See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/is-there-a-way-to-restart-a-modified-addon

Comment: @iKlsR I have compiled Blender as a Python3 module so I don't have access to the GUI. I install an addon and enable it using the function you pointed. I then save the user preferences using `bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()` and exit Python.Next time that I do `import bpy` I don't see the addon API being added to the bpy module.Do you know how I can fix that?If I run the same exact script in Blender terminal (when using the GUI) everything works.(You may answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118584/why-the-addon-installation-succeeds-but-the-api-is-not-accessible-through-the-bp))

Comment: Where is the path so that I can install it manually by copying a folder?

Answer (score 7):

This is an alternative method that works well with multiple file addons as well:

Move or create an addon directory into the addons folder of your blender settings:

Example for Linux and Blender 2.69:

```
/home/$user/.blender/2.69/scripts/addons/m3addon
```

Example for Windows 7 and Blender 2.69:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.69\scripts\addons
```

Example for Windows XP and Blender 2.69:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.69\scripts\addons
```

Example for Mac OSX and Blender 2.69:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Blender/2.69/scripts/addons
```

Activate the addon in blender

Comment: iirc, you can install a zip file as an add-on too (multi-file add-ons are usually downloaded as a zip file), which blender then extracts into its own folder in the right place.