# Cannot find SMD export buttons

Tags: add-on

I go into Blender, and under File > User preferences > Addons > Install from file and select **io_smd_tools-1.8.5**. Then I'm trying to find an Import/Export menu item but I can't find it. Please help.

Comment: This is an English language site. Could you please ask your question in English?

Comment: Can you please translate what you are asking as best as you can to English. We could [try translating it](http://bit.ly/18CliGS) but much of the meaning might be lost.

Comment: I tried a translation, please correct if it is not what you intended to ask.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this screenshot](https://code.google.com/p/blender-smd/), the export buttons are located in the scene settings, not in the import/export menu.

Also, you should keep in mind that after installing the addon, you still have to activate it in the *addons tab* (check the button on the right).

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1688/12 for some more information on installing addons.

Comment: @JulianHzg unfortunately the link to the screenshot is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *Blender 2.68*, then there is a possibility that add-on is not loading correctly.
You need to copy both file and folder to
`\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.68\scripts\addons`.

Restart Blender after copy and enable the add-on from the user preferences. It will show up properly.