# Can blender export 2D curves to svg?

Tags: export, bezier-curves, file-format

Is it possible to convert/export 2D curves to an `svg`?

I know you could render it to a raster image and then convert it with inkscape/potrace, but it would be nice if you could keep the splines the way they are in blender.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can try Liero's addon **[Viewport to SVG](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?282824-SVG-output-script)**:

- [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/keur0yo5w4ipohw/export_svg_280.py?dl=1), [install and enable add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon).
- Add-on appears in properties panel of 3D View window (N).
- Setup output directory
- Check **Bezier Overlay** option
- Select curve objects you want to export and hit "Export SVG"

The final shape is determined by point of view (perspective/orthogonal). 
Addon exports all selected curve objects (3D curves as well).

[image]

**Note:** Bezier curve is exported with strange looking poly line version.
In Inkscape - click on this path and delete. In Illustrator – first Ungroup once (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>), than select and delete.

---

There is another add-on called **[Export SVG Format](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Inkscape_SVG_Exporter)**, which exports only active object. Shape of curve is determined by "Local Z" axis in Orthogonal view.
Addon is a bit messed up with naming – downloaded script is called "exporter.py", in blender's user preferences appears as "Export SVG Format" and in blender's File menu under Export you will find it as "Inkscape SVG".

[image]

Both addons exports only paths (no fills).

Comment: Where is export menu for 'Viewport to SVG'?

Comment: @Wilf I think there is no separate menu except what you can see from my screenshot above.

Comment: @Wilf could you elaborate? I'm not sure where I should be looking for the Properties panel. It's likely there's an issue with my install but for all I know I just don't know what icon to click on and menu to expand.

Comment: @jozxyqk - what OS and version of blender are you using?

Comment: @Wilf FC21, v2.72, addons show "Import-Export: Viewport to SVG" checked. I found the properties panel. I found which one the properties panel is (the whole bottom right section, under the outliner).

Comment: @jozxyqk (and others like me who forgot...) - For 'Viewport to SVG' in Blender 2.68, you can find the export menu under 'View3d > Properties'. Basically click the 'View' Menu at the bottom, and click properties (or press 'n'). Note the extension needs to be placed in the `CONFIG_DIR/2.**/scripts/addons`, and if you enable it in the Addons settings you probably will want to press 'Save user settings' (bottom left) afterwards. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/ZOb8e60.jpg) is a screenshot if it helps.

Comment: As example "Bezier Overlay" feature can perfectly export very complex and deformed curves :) http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343747-Export-Bezier-Curve-to-SVG-as-Bezier&p=2693358&viewfull=1#post2693358

Comment: @vklidu your edit was substantial enough to warrant your own answer, instead of editing somebody else's post.

Comment: Download link is broken. Please fix or remove.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy I have updated the link.