# Export smooth SVG using Freestyle

Tags: export, freestyle

I'm using Freestyle in Blender to export a drawing to an SVG file. The file can be found here: http://www.speedyshare.com/dxsfw/box.blend

When rendered as a png it looks like this

[image]

I was interested in rendering only the "net" mesh and so isolated that in a group and rendered only that as an SVG. When opening it in Inkscape the resultant SVG had over 4000 objects.

[image]

Is there any way that I can get the vector to render solid, smooth lines? I understand that there still may be breaks, but can this be smoother/more solid?

Comment: I think you might find: [can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg) useful, there's alternatives to the freestyle SVG exporter.

Comment: @zeffii does that not only work with curves? I have a mesh

Comment: it's an extensive addon, it handles meshes too.