# How to make the Wireframes for these lights?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, workflow, wireframe

I am trying to reproduce on my CNC a wireframe skull that was etched on acrylic and put into an LED base. It is made by a company called Bulbing; I found it on Youtube. I was hoping that some one might be able help me with this project.
Useful [article](https://laughingsquid.com/bulbing-a-2d-led-lamp-featuring-3d-wire-frame-images/) about these lamps.

[image: reference image]

-from [Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=bulbing&tbm=isch&imgil=QHuo9e7RlNmThM%253A%253BGE9btNeGUXXECM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Flaughingsquid.com%25252Fbulbing-a-2d-led-lamp-featuring-3d-wire-frame-images%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=QHuo9e7RlNmThM%253A%252CGE9btNeGUXXECM%252C_&usg=__zrHvcvt8HTLZ9UIaSOdSjIy_7rs%3D&biw=1280&bih=705&ved=0ahUKEwjh8LjXk5nOAhUFyj4KHX1zAcQQyjcIRQ&ei=Y4ybV6GzMoWU-wH95oWgDA#imgrc=QHuo9e7RlNmThM%3A).

Edit: To clarify what the original asker is looking for, How do you take a 3d model and give it a wireframe appearance then output it as a 2d image (preferably vector)?  The objects in the picture are flat pieces of clear acrylic with LEDs at the bottom.  The light reflects off the engraved areas, and if a 2d view of a 3d wireframe is engraved it has the 3d effect shown in the image.

Comment: Please limit the scope of your question. What part of the process do you need help with?

Comment: Surely a naive question, but, Is that to be 3D printed or rendered ?

Comment: he said a CNC machine, which is beyond the scope of our site, as you have to use STL image files and other programs to operate it. he has the skull, and would like to etch the surface to cause the light to catch in the wireframed areas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about CNC cutting, and not about blender.

Comment: I expect you would be interested in [blendercam](http://blendercam.blogspot.com.au/) but while you could machine an object that you modelled I doubt you could etch lines onto an existing physical object, I would try something like pcb etching where you cover the object in an acid proof material and scratch off the lines where you want the acid to take off the surface.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg/6677#6677

Comment: forget i said anything about the cnc machine. i was hopeful someone would be able to help me create a image in a 2d mode to a wireframe mode. from reading into blender the image has to have points or vectors so the lines or wireframe can be connected. and to (radish) it is about blender, i would try to help someone to the right path, instead of voting the question off ((ah)). thank you for all the other responses. sambler, thank you for your help. the pictures you see are engraved on a laser or router cnc.

Comment: This question is too broad, and looks like it is more of a 3D illustration type of work than a 3D modelling question. So what have you got so far? Where exactly in your workflow are you stuck? You could use either freestyle or [Blender SVG Output Script](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?282824-SVG-output-script) to extract a 2D representation of your 3D model and export it as an SVG vector file that you can import into other software.

Comment: Is this question about doing stuff in Blender or getting Blender models out into CNC? I don't see a much of a Blender related question here...

Comment: I think this should be closed as well... My honest interpretation of the OP is that {I stumbled on this cool thing, here is all "Their" info, help me steal it}.

Comment: I think the question is if you have a 3D model like a skull, how can you convert it into a 2D wireframe that gives the illusion to be a 3D part? not saying this is related or not, from my side I am not aware if blender can help with this conversion, but I am interested to know as well

Answer (score 3):

This is actually really quite straightforward by using Freestyle and the Freestyle SVG Exporter add-on.

Start by enabling the Freestyle SVG Exporter add-on.

[image: enable SVG Exporter add-on]

The add-on gives you an additional panel in the Render settings that allow you to configure the generation of SVG files. Whenever a frame is rendered, the add-on will also generate an SVG file containing the freestyle layer only.

[image: svg exporter panel]

Setup your mesh and mark the desired edges as 'Freestyle Edge'. Configure Freestyle to render just those edges and render the result.

[image: Configure freestyle edges]

Once rendered you should find an SVG file alongside the rendered image containing just the freestyle edges.

[image: resultant SVG]

Comment: I followed your answer but the option name in the Freestyle panel is "Edge Mark" - your panel is not wide enough and the words are cutting off. I was looking for a "Freestyle SVG" pane until I noticed the "Freestyle" rendered also needs to be active.

Comment: @Luciano thanks for the comment - yes - for this answer I’d assumed a basic understanding of Freestyle. There are plenty of other questions and tutorials available that can explain freestyle and its setting better than I can here. The setup of freestyle depends on which lines of the model the user actually wants to highlight.