# Output outline data

Tags: export

Is there any way to output the outline ONLY of a surface - primarily 2D, such as the outline from a font? I can see it, but no matter what I try, when it is output in .ply format, it breaks it up into triangle or quads.

Comment: Either use [Freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/index.html?highlight=freestyle), particularly the [Freestyle SVG Exporter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/export_svg.html?highlight=freestyle), or use the [SVG Viewport Export Script](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg)

Comment: Thanks! The SVG Viewport exporter didnt do fonts, but the Freestyle  SVG Exporter outputs them nicely.