# How to export whole scene so I can import it in Illustrator?

Tags: rendering, export, add-on, svg

I am creating a book cover and I want a 3D illustration in it. My cover should display a 3D object exactly as it looks in design mode (surface view). This is my scene:

[image]

I would like to be able to import it in Illustrator as it looks like in the picture (like no colours, no materials, just the raw surface object).

How to achieve it?

#### No screenshot

Of course this would be possible by just taking a screenshot, but I want a vector object that I can manipulate inside an Illustrator picture, also it matters to me when it comes to the quality of the picture.

#### Freestyle add-on

This add-on is very strange, it only exports paths so what is exported in SVG is a path and that's it. How about surfaces?

Comment: one possible way could be tracing the "screenshot" (or, better, an OpenGL viewport render) with the vector program. Ususally this is used to get 2d vector shapes from images, then import them into blender. I don't think blender can "render" that object as 2d vector shaded...  a "contour" vector 2d object is possible though (eg: freestyle)

Comment: I know about Tracing and it is not always the best option unfortunately. It seems strange to me that an SVG export of a Blender scene is not possible...

Comment: you say "no colours, no materials" but also "exactly as it looks in design mode (surface view)" imho in the 3d view it _has_ a material (maybe a default one) and colors, shades... you could try either a freestyle svg export or a uvmap svg export (projected from view), then in the vector program shade faces... but I know it would be hard...

Comment: You are right, as-is I basically meant, no rendering, as it looks in the viewport.Also, uvmap? What is it?  have tried freestyle and it is terrible :( What is the other option you suggested? Ah thanks btw for providing input so far :)

Comment: Freestyle does not look terrible if you set it up correctly. Exporting vector data is not what Blender is really used for, the only viable option is .svg which is possible either from Freestyle or should be [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg) as well (latest messages in BA thread). It is not clear why do you need surface object exported as vector; probably that's about contour of that object which is easier to trace from render made with Freestyle

Comment: See the SVG export add-on mentioned here [Can blender export 2D curves to svg?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg)