# Export mesh as 2D svg file

Tags: export, add-on, svg, 2d

With the reference [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6675/can-blender-export-2d-curves-to-svg) with the Top Addon. I have exported a simple cube with green color. I did not get the same result with the material and the shape (view) in Blender i have set. But the output is totally different in Illustrator.

**Blender Material**

[image]

**Illustrator Colors when imported**

[image]

Why there is difference in colors. How to get the similar color. Any suggestion or help. Thanks