# How do I install a python script in OS X 10.6.8?

Tags: customization, add-on, osx

I've seen scripts I'd like to use, but I'm unfamiliar with making system files like the .blend file visible in OS X and then editing them. So, is there an easy way to install them manually?

Even more ideally, is it easy for anyone else to make an addon for installing scripts? It seems like something that would be a great feature for Blender.

Comment: What do you mean by a script? Do  you mean an [addon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon?rq=1)?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know the difference between the two. What I'm thinking is I've seen these scripts and I'd like some way to add them into Blender:
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh

Comment: Oh, it looks like that "Install from file" is the way to do it...is that right?

Comment: That's great...the tutorials on YouTube I'd seen never mentioned this and required 3rd party software.