# Precisely move the 3D cursor

Tags: interface, 3d-view, workflow, 3d-cursor

The 3D cursor can be moved by simply <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> clicking anywhere in the viewport. Is there a faster and easier way to position the 3D cursor?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

#### An updated 2.8 answer can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160470/2217)

---

In both edit mode and object mode; press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the Properties. Scroll down to the *3D cursor*. There are three number fields one each for the X, Y, and Z axes.
For finer control use <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging the mouse. Also see the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html#d-cursor-panel).

[image: The 3D Cursor panel]

Note the coordinates are always in *Global*, how the transform orientation is set makes no difference.

Comment: This answer is so simple - but thinking back it has saved me SO MUCH time. I think it deserves a bounty :)

Comment: Looks like this changed in 2.8.  `N` appears to bring up a Transform menu that's scoped to the current selection.  -- Any idea how to do it in Blender 2.8?
*Edit:* looks like just to the right of the menu there are three tiny tabs, `Item`, `Tool`, and `View`.  If you click on `View` you can edit the cursor location.  Super bizarre, but it's there.

Comment: For me I had to hold `Shift` while dragging the mouse for finer control on v2.8.

Answer (score 68):

Have a look at the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html). You can also use the snap menu pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

[image: snap menu]

> - **Cursor to Selected**
>     *Snaps the cursor to the center of the current selection.*
> - **Cursor to Center**
>     *Snaps the cursor to the origin of the scene (location 0,0,0).*
> - **Cursor to Grid**
>     *Snaps the cursor to the nearest visible grid lines.*
> - **Cursor to Active**
>     *Snaps the cursor to the active (last selected) object, edge, face or vertex.*

Answer (score 41):

There is a great addon called [Enhanced 3D Cursor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Enhanced_3D_Cursor) that makes positioning the 3D cursor *much* easier.
After [installing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1689/2217) and enabling it there will be a new panel in the *properties region*.

[image: panel in properties region]
That is only part of the addon's power.
Now when you press <kbd>F10</kbd> or simply click and hold the <kbd>LMB [image: LMB]</kbd> the 3D cursor will snap to your objects' faces. Furthermore if you hold shift the 3D cursor will snap to the center of the faces.

[image: animated gif of moving cursor]

After you started moving the 3D cursor you can type in values to move the 3D cursor, using the arrow keys to change the axes fields. (note the 3D view header)
[image: animated gif - changing the values]

There are also bookmarks for the location of the 3D cursor.
[image: animated gif - book marks for the 3D cursor]

Docs for the addon on the [wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Enhanced_3D_Cursor#Usage).

Answer (score 29):

In 2.8+ the 3D cursor has changed quite a bit.

Using the default blender keymap in left click select mode the keyboard shortcut to move the 3D cursor is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd>.

There is the "Cursor" tool (found in the top of the tool bar) that when active allows you to move the 3D cursor by simply <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> (just like in 2.7x).
As a side note when using right click select <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> moves the 3D cursor no matter the active tool.
From the tool's options (Tool tab of the [sidebar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/properties/sidebar.html) <kbd>N</kbd>, or the *Active Tool* tab of the *Properties* Editor) you can change the projection type and the orientation.
[image: Cursor Tool Options]

You can still move the 3D cursor by entering in a location (and rotation). That field is in the sidebar <kbd>N</kbd> under the *View* tab, then in the *3D Cursor* section.
[image: 3D cursor location and rotation]

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, was having trouble locating the 3D cursor menu.

Answer (score 16):

**Python Console**

[image]

Can enter values into the python console. `C` is a convenience variable for context.  The 3D cursor is `C.scene.cursor_location`.  Using autocomplete <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and history <kbd>⬆</kbd>.<kbd>⬇</kbd> reduces the need for a ton of typing.

```
>> C.scene.cursor_location
Vector((4.0, 4.0, 4.000024795532227))

>>> C.scene.cursor_location = (0, 0, 0)
>>> C.scene.cursor_location.xy = (4, 4)
>>> C.scene.cursor_location.x += 10
>>> C.scene.cursor_location
Vector((14.0, 4.0, 0.0))

>>> m = Matrix.Rotation(radians(30), 3, (0, 1, 1))
# rotate 30 degrees around axis (0, 1, 1)
>>> C.scene.cursor_location = m * C.scene.cursor_location
>>> C.scene.cursor_location
Vector((10.710140228271484, 8.681798934936523, -4.681799411773682))
```

**New in 2.80**

`Scene.cursor` is the cursor "object".

```
>>> C.scene.cursor.location
Vector((0.790132999420166, 2.7452266216278076, 0.7758755683898926))
```

Please note that as of 2.80 it is also possible to set the rotation of the cursor.  It now has the same 3 modes of rotation as an object.

To reset the cursor rotation, via the py console.

To set to Euler XYZ rotation to degrees (30, 0, 45)

```
>>> C.scene.cursor.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'  

>>> C.scene.cursor.rotation_euler = (radians(30), 0, radians(45))
```

[How do I reset the 3d cursor rotation in 2.80?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125191/how-do-i-reset-the-3d-cursor-rotation-in-2-80)

There is a new tool dedicated to the cursor, which *hopefully* over time will also include the UI to set loc and rot.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to move the *3D cursor* to the center of the scene, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to place the 3D cursor at the center of something, lets say is an edge, go to edit mode press w to subdivide, select the created vertex, press shift+s then 'cursor to selected', the same thing with a plane, select the plane, create a loop cut by pressing ctrl+r, select the newly created edge and repeat above process.

Comment: Not sure that adding new geometry is the right way to go about positioning the 3D cursor.  The same can be done by selecting geometry and snapping.