# How can a RGB color value be copied from reference image or render?

Tags: interface

In the render view one can see the RGB values while pressing LMB.

[image]

Can these values be copied to the clipboard in order to paste them into a color widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender can copy any color value from the 3D viewport directly into the color widget.
The little icon "Sample data block from the 3D view" allows to pick a color value:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Haha, nice selfie ;).

Comment: @Gonzou I hope this helpful for others, I stumbled over this today (haven't seen this icon in 2 years of twiddling with Blender).

Comment: I feel your pain. Sometimes it's is hard to discover the simpliest thing. Happily this site exists :).

Comment: @stacker that is how it was with me and the [3D cursor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13828/2217).