# Move 3D cursor via current active object?

Tags: python

You cannot really drag the 3D cursor or snap it in Blender which is not ideal.

So I thought one could do this:

```
Start (via pressing a button/key)
    make new empty at 3D cursor position
    set 3D cursor location = active object location (the empty)
    Stop (via pressing a button/key)
        delete created empty
Exit
```

The idea is that when I move the empty the 3d cursor will always follow it. One can snap the empty to a vertex in object mode easily and thus positioning the 3D cursor.

And then the user is satisfied with the cursor position a key is pressed to exit the command chain the empty will be removed and the 3D cursor remains where it got moved to.

Is this a possible idea and would one suggest a better way?

*Please excuse my brutish attempt.*

Comment: there is a template in blender that is somehow close to this check t out : templates->operator_modal_draw.py

Comment: Check the [Enhanced 3D Cursor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Enhanced_3D_Cursor.) add-on.  ..dragging, snapping

Comment: Take a look at [Precisely move the 3D cursor](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13828/2217), the answers there may have a solution so that you don't have to code your own.

Comment: PivoPro has an interesting idea actually similar to the idea I formulated on top. But enhanced 3D Cursor seems to use a more pro approach with raymarching if I understand that right, cause most of the code is like French to me >> sad face <<