# Change object origin precisely?

Tags: objects, 3d-cursor

So here is my current state:
[image: object as it is now]

I want to move the object origin (small yellow dot) exactly in the middle but to the right so when I mirror the object it will work correctly.

I can't figure out how to do it. I know how I can move the 3d cursor and change the objects center to match the 3d cursor.  However, I do not know how to get the 3d cursor to the exact spot.

I know where I can input the exactly location of the 3d cursor but I don't know how to SEE the current object center so I know the proper Y/Z pair to put in.

How can this be done easily?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/precisely-move-the-3d-cursor

Comment: Please use the tools on this site to uplad images. If the link goes down your question might not make sense to other users in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There a couple of ways:

1. Tool shelf > Tools [tab] > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry or Origin to Center of Mass (which could be the same depending on your object)
2. You can move the 3D cursor to any point related to the object mesh. In edit mode, snap it to any point of the object mesh, or the mean point of any selection within the mesh, like this: Shift+S > Cursor to Selected or Active or Center.  Then tab back to object mode and as in #1 ... Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor

Answer (score 1):

Method A:
in edit mode: put a vertex in the exact place you want the object's center to be, select it, hit shift+s and select cursor to selected.

Tab out of edit mode and

in object mode: hit control+alt+shift+c and select origin to 3d cursor

Method B:
in your mirror modifier chose a mirror object that you can move around and you won't be constrained to the mirrored object's origin (i have rarely used this method so i can't give precise instructions but i hope you can figure it out)

Answer (score 0):

In the N-panel you can select *Tool* -> *Options* -> *Transform* -> *Affect Only Origins*.

[image]

Now any <kbd>G</kbd> *Grab*, <kbd>S</kbd> *Scale*, or <kbd>R</kbd> *Rotate* operations will only move the Origin points, the mesh will be unaffected in world space.  You can use the *Adjust Last Operation* panel to make precise movements.

Important to note that any scaling will be reflected in the Objects' transform values even though the mesh is unchanged, so you may have to apply scale to any objects you've changed.  You also need to remember to disable this option in the N-panel to return to normal transform methods.