# How do you execute bpy operations in the python console that requires you to hover your mouse over the 3D view port?

Tags: python, 3d-view, operator

I just want to enter `bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()` in my python console just to see how it works.

I am getting the error:

`"RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center.poll() failed, context is incorrect"`.

I know I have to make sure my mouse cursor is hovering over the 3D viewport to execute this, but if move my mouse cursor over to the 3D viewport I can't press enter on the python console. This question sounds super stupid I know, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Override the context. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add   (probable duplicate)

Comment: Also related, there is no need to use that operator. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101892/15543