# Blender Origin was unintentionally move, set back to 0 0 0

Tags: unity, origin

I found this : https://blenderartists.org/t/set-objects-origin-to-world-0-0-0/442642/2
this : https://www.katsbits.com/codex/origin/
this : https://daler.github.io/blender-for-3d-printing/mesh_modeling/object-origin.html
and this : https://gamedevacademy.org/how-to-import-blender-models-into-unity-your-one-stop-guide/

All of which through their blatant omission of mentioning a way to reset the origin to zero seem to confirm what I'm worried about: this may not be an option in blender.

And clicking around with the 3D cursor won't help, I need perfect 0,0,0.

---

What I'm going to do as a workaround is to close and reopen my project in order to generate a new 3D cursor, which by default should be a perfect 0,0,0

I really want a non-hack approach.

Comment: You can set the [origin of the object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin/14296#14296) to the center and you can even [set the 3d cursor to (0,0,0)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/precisely-move-the-3d-cursor/160470#160470) to move the origin of an object precisely. Frequently asked questions... Not sure what you're asking for, please edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

All of the above is correct, but it leads me to wonder something. Doesn't applying all transformations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) force the origin of an object to return to the world space origin? And in one step? If so, wouldn't this be what the OP wants? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Agreed applying transform (location in this case) will move local to global origin in single step.  Use `Ctrl` for keyboard formatting. ... Answer could possibly lose the pondering.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You're absolutely right. No idea why I didn't think of that :).

Answer (score 1):

Reset the cursor location to 0,0,0 in the properties panel either by manually typing into each axis or hover over one of the values and click (right/left depending on your default settings) and click reset all to default.

Reset objects to 0,0,0 by selecting the object, click "Object" menu item (in Object mode) select => Transform => Origin to 3D cursor