# How to Install Three.js Exporter in Blender 2.72b

Tags: export, add-on

Does anyone know how to add on the Three.js File exporter in blender 2.72b I can not for the life of me get it installed.

~Thanks.

Comment: See if [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon) question is any help.

Comment: If that post still doesn't answer your question, could you post some details on what specifically happens (or doesn't happen) when you try to install it? As it is now we have no clue as to what could possibly be going wrong.