# Update and add-on problem

Tags: add-on, installation, blend4web

I have Blender 2.73 and want to update to 2.75 but when I do it does not unzip correctly or completely, and it does not show up in my control panel where the installed programs show up. Also I want to install the Blend4web add-on but the install from file does not work. I really don't know about scripting and all that so I would need a detailed walkthrough if I was going to install it that way. Can anyone help me with these issues?

Comment: This video explains installing the Blend4Web add-on
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH7rirEYVYI

Answer (score 2):

When you do the update the installer file it should be an .msi file. if the one you have is zipped, unzip the file in a temporary file location, and the double click the *[filename]*.msi file.  You should ensure that you install it in the same directory as previous installations, if you did not use the default for your previous or first install.

The addon, after it is unzipped should be a *.py file; you can find help on this installation at this location: [Installing an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I will try the .msi file. Will post if that works for me.

Comment: The install for the 2.75 worked using the .msi, thank you However, the install for the addon did not, no matter what I tried. This is a new install of Blend4web and not an update like you thought. The only option it gives me for a download is a zip file. I did unzip to it's own folder but I did not see an .msi install file but I did find a bunch of .py files in one of the many folder for this addon. Do I have to find each and every .py file in this addon and use the "import from file" option in the user preferences section to make this work? That seems to be the long way to go.

Comment: I would look up how to install add-ons in blender stack exchange; then if you still have a question, ask that one specifically. Hope that helps.  I'd have to look it up again; but, I think it can be as simple as extracting the .zip file contents to the right Blender folder (addons).  At least the last time I did it I didn't think there was much to it.