# Export TGA or BMP textures for WebGL

Tags: export, webgl

Bablylon.js has a exporter plug-in for Blender. Works great, but some of the models that I get from turbosquid have TGA based textures. Since WebGL needs textures in JPG, PNG, or other web friendly formats, I am forced to convert hunderds of TGA  or BMP textures by hand to JPG or PNG.

Does anyone have a batch way of doing this?

(also I am specifically looking for suburban scenes such as: 
http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/housing-development-rt-3d-model/760773

But they do their trees as two-intersecting planes (great for Max 3DS). But WebGL engines like sprites. So I also need a way to convert those artifacts..

(see below for the tree meshes that will not work in WebGL):

[image]

Comment: you can batch convert stuff with photoshp. i assume gimp has a similar feature.

Comment: Yes, I have photoshop, but this would not handle all the references in the x.blend file to the .tga files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [addon](https://github.com/Tlousky/production_scripts/wiki/batch_converter.py) to batch convert image files with blender.

After [installing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1688/2217) the addon, the usage is simple:

1. Tell the addon where the folder of images is (must contain only the images to convert)
2. Give it a output folder
3. Set the render settings correctly (you will want PNG)
4. Click the *Batch convert* button.

---

To keep the original file sizes, check the *Keep Original Resolution* check box in the Batch Converter settings in the tool shelf.
[image: batch convert settings]

Comment: That looks good. I hope it also handles the texture references. But it asks that all the file outputs have the same dimension. However my input texture files are all different sizes.

Comment: @Dr.YSG see my edit. As to the file path for each model's textures. Nope, this addon will not. It is possible to write a script to do that, but out of the scope of the batch image converter.