# Addons: Only some .zips will install

Tags: add-on, customization, installation

Why is it that if I go to install an add-on from User **Preferences > Add-ons > Install from File...** and choose a *.ZIP, some add-ons will install, while others will return me to the User Preferences with nothing having happened (as far as I can tell)?

Is there a specific file structure required in the .ZIP? I get many add-ons from GitHub, using the *Download Zip* button, and even there installation of the actual Zip file only works some of the time.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can install from zip directly if the zip is either:

- a zipped single .py file

  ```py
    addon_name.zip
         |  
         addon_name.py
  ```
- a zipped folder, important that it's not a zip that contains a folder first.

  - **these will work** because the folder structure is at the expected level. The `__init__`.py is directly inside the zip ("top level").

    - https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok
    - https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes

  ```
    addon_name.zip
         |  
         addon_foo.py   
         __init__.py
  ```

  this will also work

  ```py
    addon_name.zip
         |  
         addon_name_folder
                |
                addon_foo.py   
                __init__.py
  ```

  - for instance: **this zip will fail**, because the add-on folder is nested too deep, there's another folder inside the zip:

    - [https://github.com/zeffii/TubeTool](https://github.com/zeffii/TubeTool/tree/morph_targets)  (this is a link to a branch that first has an extra level of folder nesting)
    - Github will generate a zip from that repo that looks like this:

  ```
    repository_name.zip
         |  
         repository_name_folder
              |
              first_folder_in_repo
                      | 
                      addon_foo.py   
                      __init__.py
  ```

Zipped add-ons with a structure that doesn't work with the install-from-file feature may or may not have a good reason for being that way.

Comment: I wondered about this too, good to know

Comment: Can I get a fact check on this? The last one should not fail as the `.zip` file is extracted into the add-ons folder (as it [does in the source code](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blame/eb6fe5fa94b86a0a20742e06bf1e68b4cbaf6693/release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/wm.py#L2062)) and the `__init__.py` file will get picked up by Blender. The system has been this way since Blender `2.6` according to `git blame`. I structured my add-on like the last one and it works fine...

Comment: i'm going to agree, that last written zip structure should prove no problem to the installer. i'll edit my answer. (if you look at the zip of the github repo i linked to, you'll see I missed a nested folder in the example here)

Comment: i'll edit it further when at the desktop.

Comment: For Blender 2.9 though self installed addons will not always show up n the search bar. any ideas on how to solve that ?