# Addons not appearing when I search for them

Tags: customization

I am trying to install a addon that lets me [import MMD](https://github.com/sugiany/blender_mmd_tools) files but it is not appearing after I press the button "install from file" and select the file.
Here are some pictures of what I do to install it.

[image]

[image]

**As seen above it is nowhere to be found!** (sorry for the poor quality pictures)

Comment: Have you looked at http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install?rq=1  zip addon install will fail if the addon folder is not the root of the zip... which is often the case for github zips.

Comment: Voted to close as link above answers this for a generic case.  What you need to do is drop the mmd_tools folder from the zip into one of your addons folders.  It's a toss up when hosting on git to use the root folder as the addon folder as there is the git README.md etc... unfortunately that makes install from zip add a gitrepo_master folder in your addons folder, and the addon folder inside that, which isn't picked up by blender as an addon module.