# Installation addon in Blender 2.78

Tags: python, add-on

In would like to install an addon, but when I try to enable the addon I get an error message "Import error, no module named 'myname'.

In previous versions of Blender I had no problem in installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install

Comment: No, I do not have a zip file, just a .py file.

Comment: Did you try zipping your .py file?

Comment: That did not help either

Answer (score 1):

The filename is not allowed to include "."

So my_addon_10.py is correct, but not my_addon_1.0.py.