# Add-on - Error with Module

Tags: add-on

I was downloading some interesting looking add-ons and I copied the script to the addon folder like I was supposed to but when I tried enabling it in Blender it gave me this error (the addon is [MCexport](https://github.com/FlowSoft87/MCExport)):
[image]

Comment: the add-on are not copied, they are installed, there is a big difference, except for some exceptions but they are always clarified by the creator and gives a list of reasons why to do it that way

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install)  You want the files you see in git repo in a folder `.../addons/MCexport/`  I have the feeling you have copied `MinecraftCubeModelExporter.py` to your addons folder, whereas it should be in `.../addons/MCexport/Export/MinecraftCubeModelExporter.py
`  (and all the other files accordingly)