# 2.80 Addon zip file installation

Tags: python

Will 2.80 support zip file installation of addons? What are the requirements for the zip structure and its contents? I have [tried multiple directory structures (as noted in this related question)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install), all of which fail to import in 2.80 (my addon is a python package/directory, containing an `__init__.py` etc).

EDIT: It seems like I should be using the "Install Add-on from file" button in the user preferences to perform the install, not dropping the zip in the blender addons folder. That also gives an error message, see the bottom of this post for that.

**Working/runnable: Contents of the actual package, NOT IN ZIP FORMAT (normal py package/dir), verified to run/import in 2.80 (git.351f537fa83):**

[image]

**Broken: Addon as a zip file, structure 1 (__init__ and all files directly inside top level of zip file).**

[image]

**Also broken: structure 2 (named package folder containing __init__ and all files directly inside top level of zip file)**

[image]

**The error message is the same in both cases:**

[image]

**Install via button, also broken: "Install Add-on from file" button in the user preferences, using a zip file in "structure 1" format above.**

[image]

Comment: I would go for structure 2.  User can either install from file (using zip as the file) or drag the folder from the zip into addons folder.

Comment: Good point. I'm hoping the import from file will be fixed sometime soon so that I can verify it with the install button, maybe I'll submit a bug report...

Answer (score 1):

make sure your add-on is specifically written for 2.8, Blenders API had been drastically changed and most add-ons if not all are behind re written to be compatible. it seems your add-on is using a function that had been replaced or merged. correct me if I'm wrong.