# Can't Import an Addon that I wrote

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Let me just get straight to the point!

I use visual studio code to write my addon. If I open it through visual studio code, it works fine, but when I try to import it into Blender by loading the *init*.py of my addon. It won't show up.

While there were tutorials online on how to create an addon in vs code, but none of them show how to actually export addons from vs code and load them into blender.
So now I'm kind of lost. I couldn't find this in forums and not sure how people figure this out by themselves, but here I am asking for help.

And I highly appreciate every answer I could get!
Thanks in advance!

My *init*.py is in screenshots[image] [image]

Comment: Have you created a .zip of your whole add-on and tried to install it in the preferences *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*?

Comment: I did it trough the preferences, and yes I tried the zip, for the 2nd time now, but no luck. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: Just to be clear you don't find it listed among the other add-ons? Are there any errors printed to the console (on Windows: *Window > Toggle System Console*; Linux, macOS: requires starting Blender from the terminal)

Comment: Ok, here is the thing man... you mentioned if I had tried to install it trough preferences and trough zip. Which were the only ones I tried, so you gave me the idea of just doing it manually by just dropping it in the addons folder. And IT WORKED! Now I'm not sure why it didn't work trough zip and stuff like that, but at least it worked this way.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install  Please post code as text in a code block.