# Why can't I enable JewelCraft addon?

Tags: add-on

[image: The error message]

Tried reinstalling Blender, the add on itself, don't know what to do next.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install  You do not want a folder named `xxxx-master` in your addon folders.  It will not import (install) properly.  Try renaming without the `"-master"`

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [installation guide](https://github.com/mrachinskiy/jewelcraft#how-to-install).

You receive error message because you are trying to install add-on repository instead of release. Make sure you download add-on release using link provided in step one of installation guide.