# Addon Hairnet won't install

Tags: add-on, customization

I'm trying to get the Hairnet add-on installed on Blender 2.8.1, but it won't show I've had the same issue since I found out about add-ons.

It shows that it's in my Blender folder, but it doesn't show up in my preferences not even if I I scrolled down.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Download the *latest release* `HairNet.zip` instead of the entire repository: https://github.com/Jandals/HairNet/releases from github. Also please provide a link to the add-on next time so we don't have to search for it.

Comment: Thank you. The link I used originally wasn't effective, but that was was.

Comment: @brockmann I think you could post this as an answer.

Comment: Actually thinking about asking a question how to intall addons hosted on github since this issue came up multiple times last week @RobertGützkow

Comment: @brockmann https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install