# MultiFile Add-on with single python file

Tags: python, add-on

I am making an add-on in blender that has one python file. In the past, I have been able to just import this add-on as a single python file by itself, but I need to use a .zip file for this because my add-on needs a .blend file to work. I have tried installing my current add-on as a zip with files as so:

```
addon.zip:
--addon.py
--addon.blend
```

But the add-on doesn't show up in Preferences. How do I make this work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the included add-ons that come with Blender as examples. If you are on Windows, that will most likely be `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender [version number]\[version number]\scripts\addons\`
If you go to any of the folders there, you will see what would be in the zip file if it was a zipped addon:

[image]

The main addon file is `__init__.py`, you have to have one like that.