# Exporting Motion Tracking Data from Blender to After Effects

Tags: animation, export, camera, tracking

Is there a way that I can track footage in Blender, and export it to After Effects? I don't have money for specialized tracking software.

For reference I would like to do everything up until [2:21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hfth77B1vUk) (track, make points etc.) in Blender, and then do the rest in AE.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the tracker used in the video is the one built into After Effects, so if you have AE, you should be able to use it. But if you really need to use Blender and export, I'm pretty sure there is an addon for exporting camera animation to After Effects.

Comment: Just so you know, Blenders Motion Tracking tools, while they do have some automation, they aren't as automated as the tools in AE. You will end up spending a decent portion of time just tracking markers, whereas in AE, it get's done for you in a few minutes.

Comment: There is a plugin for this

Comment: I have CS5 and it does not have a 3D tracker like CS6+

Comment: @cegaton I shall now write an answer.... I wrote that comment and then had to dash

Comment: @SirNih4l I agree, the tracker for AFX CS5 is terrible. I scrolled quickly through the tutorial you linked and it would be very easy to do not only the tracking but the whole tutorial in Blender.

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin for this:

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Adobe_After_Effects

### Setup

To enable it you can use the user preferences *File*>*User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>)

Go to the addons tab

Search for "After Effects" if the plugin pops up, enable it.

If nothing comes up, [download the addon](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/io_export_after_effects.py), and install it using these steps:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1689/3127

### Usage

Select the objects and camera etc that you wish to export, and go to *File*>*Export*>*Adobe After Effect (.jsx)*

Save the file.

Open After Effects (Version > CS2)

*File*>*Scripts*>*Run Script File* and select your file. It will ask you to name the comp. Any name will work

Next, after it is done, go into the Project panel and open up your comp. A bunch of nulls and a camera should be there, matching the motion of the ones in blender.

Comment: I have the latest version of Blender. I track some points in blender but when i move it over to after effects the null objects do not stay stationary they move with the camera. I am not able to keep them locked in one position.

Comment: @SirNih4l Can you include a blend file, I have no idea why that should be happening