# blender cannot see three.js addon

Tags: add-on, three.js

i want to use blender models in [three.js](http://threejs.org/). To import blender models to 3.js we have to use blender exporter [addon](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender)   so i follow a tutorial and do every step correctly .i have included folder inside addon directory.but when i restart blender i can't see a three.js addon . i'm using blender 2.72 version .

[image]

as you can see there is no addon as 3.js

[image]

Comment: Did you activate the addon in User preferences?

Comment: @maegmaeg this user reference panel.isn't it? i can't see the addon to active

Comment: When you go into user preferences under file > user preferences or simple hit ctrl + alt + u, you must activate the addon in the addon tab. When you can't find it there, you should check if there is a init-file in the three.js folder.

Comment: @maegmaeg ohh i thought above windows is the user preferences panel.but your shortcut help me to find real preferences tab.ok i did it and it works well .thanks you so much.plz provide this as a answer i will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an addon after copying it to Blenders addon folder, you must activate it first in *User Preferences*. You find it under: *File > User preferences* or you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

In the *Add-on* tab you can search for your addon and activate it by ticking the checkbox.

Also see: [Installing an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon)