# How to install prototype glTF export addon/module?

Tags: add-on

I've read about [Installing Add-ons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon) but I still can't get [blendergltf](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf) installed correctly.  I understand it's an early prototype, but I believe it to be in a state where it can at least install and try a simple export.  I'm using Blender 2.76b.

This addon ships with two files, `__init__.py` and `blendergltf.py`.  I made a zip file with both of them, and selected "Install from file..." on the zip file from user preferences.  Blender has dutifully unzipped both Python files and installed them into the correct `...\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons` folder on Windows.  I have been able to get other (simpler) addons to load from that same folder.

In the Blender system console, I see:

> fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.76\scripts\addons\blendergltf.py'

So sure, `blendergltf.py` is structured as a module, not an addon.  The `bl_info` definition is in `__init__.py` which is in that same folder, attempting to load the other script as a module.

Near as I can tell, the module is being loaded as an addon while the actual addon is being ignored.  I must be doing something wrong.  The addon does not show up at all, not even in the disabled state under User Preferences -> Addons tab -> "Testing" category, which is where I would expect to find the checkbox to enable the new addon.

How can I get this installed?

Comment: both files need to be in /Blender/2.76/scripts/addons/blendergltf/ folder.  Create a blendergltf folder in addons and move the files there.

Comment: Ah, they need their own folder under addons, thanks!  I tried so many crazy permutations but I didn't think to make a subfolder.  I guess my zip file may have worked had it contained a subfolder.  Go ahead and post that as the answer, thanks.

Comment: Rule of thumb, multiple py addons with an ` __init__.py` will have their own folder.  Single py addons with bl_info are installed in addons folder.

Comment: This is great info, and I got the plugin working, thanks!  If you re-post this as an answer instead of a comment, I'll accept the answer.