# How to run Batch Rename Datablocks Addon?

Tags: scripting, add-on, data-blocks

If the button [ Run Script ] does nothing and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> does nothing and right click *Run Script* does nothing. I don't even get an error message. Do I have to enable something?

This is my first ever attempt at running a python script:

https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/contrib/py/scripts/addons/object_batch_rename_datablocks.py

Wiki link: [Batch Rename Datablocks](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Batch_Rename_Datablocks)

Comment: The problem is in the script. It gets executed, but it only adds an Operator and no gui for it. You can search for the operator with *Spacebar*. The name is "Batch Rename Datablocks". If you need some gui, the script must register a class of `bpy.types.Panel`

Comment: @Jerryno, sorry just see your comment.

Comment: @lemon no problem at all, I had a chance to write an answer but did a quick comment instead. You invested the time and made a .gif, the points are yours.

Answer (score 3):

In the 3D view, type <kbd>space</kbd> then type "batch rename..." :

[image]

"Run script" just allows this to be available.

Since this is an **Addon** (not a regular script) you can make it (the operator and its functionality) permanently available, see: [How to install an Addon?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon)

Comment: It is easy and simple. Thanks. 
But what is frustratingly consistent with blender.org is I am suppose to translate:
"UI location | Search: Batch Rename Datablocks" 
Seems obvious in hindsight but for a one who is learning a new aspect this does not say to do this or this could just be a statement. It is not obvious this is an instruction or something that needs to be done for the script to work. It is all written with no consideration to the new user. Then I have to come here and bother the good folks for answers. If it wasn't for StackExchange I would not even try using blender.

Comment: @EricHuelin, I understand, but few new users need this kind of scripts as beginners.. Imagine yourself seeing MS Excel for the first time and try to play with some Visual Basic in it...

Comment: The UI pops up but have no idea how to use it. All I wanted to do is replace the period "." with something else. I want to FBX export to Maya and periods in names are incompatible with Maya.

Comment: @EricHuelin, well, the usage is to write another question for that. Could you do it ?

Comment: I just figured out what it is. It is useless for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Blender has a text editor in which you can run scripts.

Just open the text editor, paste your code and run script.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did that.
In the text editor I dragged and dropped the script and it shows the script in the text editor, I would not be able to right click Run Script otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure your script is working properly? 

Have you tried it with an other script? Maybe one you know works?