# Modelling a Rhombic triacontahedron

Tags: modeling

The [rhombic triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rhombictriacontahedron.gif) is an Archimedean solid, which consists of 30 Rhombuses

[image]

I need a model like this to be a base for one of my projects.

I thought about creating a solid with 10 hexagons as base and then subdivide it, but I couldn't manage it at the end.

Answer (score 9):

This shape can be modeled using [Extra Objects](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_Extra) addon or in a manual way.

Extra Objects addon has preset accessible for rhombic triacontahedron. You'll need to activate addon in User Preferences, see more on how to [activate / install an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon).

With addon enabled, from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> menu find *Mesh > Math function > Regular Solid*. Then you'll tweak its parameters:

[image: scr of adding mesh]

In *Last Operator* panel load preset:

[image: scr of setting up mesh]

Or change parameters for *Source*, *Vertex Truncation* and *Dual*.

To model it manually:

1. Start with icosphere, 1 subdivision.
2. Poke faces with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.. This will create geometry necessary for the middle of rombes.
3. Select one newly created vertex (from poked ones).
4. Select similar with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *Amount of connecting edges*. Scale them out along normals a bit.
5. Select all, convert to quads (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).

[image: GIF modeling mesh]

6. As resulting faces are non-planar (i.e. not all vertices are located on the same imaginary plane), make them planar using *Mesh > Clean-Up > Make Planar Faces* with around 4 iterations ([thanks to Leon Cheung](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58596/modelling-a-rhombic-triacontahedron/58601?noredirect=1#comment100632_58601)).

Comment: well : ) ... I was close : ))

Comment: For the manual method, actually you can hardly scale to make all quads planar enough in this way. I would suggest Alt J then increase the Max Face Angle parameter, then Mesh > Clean Up > Make Planar Faces, increase the Interations.

Comment: @LeonCheung you are right, they are non-planar. I thought about that but for some reason didn't check. Generally, it's still possible to scale those vertices - *Make Non-planar* will handle with the job, so there won't be non-planar ones under 5 degrees.

Answer (score 5):

You can start from a dodecahedron to do that.

[image]

The dodecahedron is a regular solid given in the '*extra object*' addon. It looks like this:

[image]

So, starting from it, the idea is to remove each edge which cut each pentagon (do that for all the pentagons):

[image]

And replace it by a center, like this:

- Extrude <kbd>E</kbd>, then scale to zero <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

Once done for all faces, you can remove all double and obtain this which is the geometry you want, except that rhombic parts are not flat:

[image]

To make them flat, select all the pentagons centers, then scale:

[image]

This scaling will be approximative, but now:

Enter edit mode again, select all, then make quad with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the first step, you needn't do that for all pentagons, just select all then X -> Limited Dissolve. Another way is selecting one of the diagonale then Shift G > Length, then  X > Only Edges & Faces, then select all and F to fill all holes with ngons.