# How to perform operation to multiple objects using python

Tags: python, scripting, physics, selection-tools

i dont know very much about python or coding, so as basic as possible.
i need to apply the same settings to multiple objects so i want to be able to loop through them and do a operation to them.
if i go to the info window i can see the command for what ive just changed and this works if i do

```
import bpy 
(whatever was in the info window)
```

e.g.

```
import bpy 
bpy.context.object.rigid_body.angular_damping = 0.830769
```

However this only works with the selected object, i want to be able to make this work for all selected objects. So i guess you loop through all the selected objects and then apply this setting to every one. 
so:

Q1) How do i loop through all selected objects?

Q2) how does the command change when you want it to work on multiple objects, because the context part makes it work on only the active object in the selection?

edit
 tried this, doesnt work

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

for o in context.selected_objects:
 object.rigid_body.angular_damping = 0.830769
```

AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute 'rigid_body'

edit again
this works! thanks batFINGER

```
 import bpy
    context = bpy.context

    for o in context.selected_objects:
     o.rigid_body.angular_damping = 0.830769
```

Comment: `for o in context.selected_objects:` loops thru all the selected objects.

Comment: @batFinger thanks, does "o" refer to the object     i tried this but i get an error --------------------------- 
import bpy


for o in context.selected_objects:
 object.rigid_body.angular_damping = 0.830769         -------------sorry i cant see any option to format this properly in comments

Comment: Might find this somewhat related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58985/15543 .

Comment: @batFINGER error was NameError: name 'context' is not defined

Comment: `context = bpy.context`  and it would be `o.rigid_body...`

Comment: @batFINGER thanks, it works now, although i don't really understand why, what the o is doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45655/discussion-between-forferdeilig-and-batfinger).