# where can I download a "text" addon?

Tags: python, mesh, add-on

I'm not very good in the subject of addons, and when I wanted to be able to add a polysphere on blender, I googled around and found an "Add_mesh_round_cube" addon which I believe should be correct. It's on the blender developer website, so I think it's quite a legitimate source:

[image]

When I selected the addon on the list (as seen above) I came to this page:

[image]

Apparently this is the python text of the addon. But I don't know how to proceed from here. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: just as a side note, what's wrong with using shift+a, add uv sphere in the 3d viewport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing an addon](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon)

Comment: Alias guru, I want to add polyspheres intead because UV-spheres will pinch detail at the poles, whereas the polysphere has only quads and the detail is all nicely distributed, and it makes for some great topology

Comment: It is included into Extra Objects addon; if you want it separate find it on [github](https://github.com/scorpion81/blender-addons/blob/master/add_mesh_extra_objects/add_mesh_round_cube.py). In general, if you see an addon in plane text, select it and save to a file with .py extension.

Answer (score 2):

Select the text and copy it, then paste it into a text editor and save it as something like `Add_mesh_round_cube.py` (make sure to give it the `.py` extension).  Now you can [load it into Blender like any other addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1688/5705).  Open the User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) and go to the Addons tab, then hit *Install From File* and select the file from your computer.  Then click the little checkmark next to it to enable it.

*Note that, as others have mentioned, the specific addon you are looking at is already bundled in Blender by default, so you can just find it in the list and enable it.*

Answer (score 1):

The Round Cube addon is included with the Extra Objects addon, which is included with the official builds. You just need to activate it.
Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to open up the User preferences. Click the Add-ons tab, then type extra in the search bar. Mark the check box next to Add Mesh: Extra Objects, then click Save User Settings and close the preferences window. The Round Cube should now show up under Mesh in the Add menu.
[image]