# F2 add-on not working

Tags: add-on

I have installed Blender 2.77 on Windows Vista. I enabled F2 add-on but it is not working. I downloaded version 1.7.2 from the add-on site and enabled that too but still did not work. I checked for any python errors in the console but no clues there too. Only when I "disable" the add-on I get message in console "Search for unknown operator mesh_ot_f2" Please note this is on disabling the add-on on enabling add-on I do not get any errors. Request you all experts to guide me how t troubleshoot this or share the solution.

Comment: Welcome to the Blender.SE. What does not work exactly ? How did you install addon ?  See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1688/1245 on details about that. Did you try to check what happens when you try to use the addon ?

Comment: @Mr Zak Thank you. Appreciate your help. My understanding is F2 add-on is now built into version 2.77 as it appeared in add-on without any separate download and installation. You need to just enable it. To check any errors while enabling it or using it, I checked blender console but no errors there except above

Comment: It is, although you noted that you "downloaded version 1.7.2 from the add-on site and enabled that too" which can lead to unexpected behaviour if original version was not uninstalled correctly. So delete / replace original file of F2, paste or install from file downloaded one and try activating and using it.

Comment: Just discovered that F2 plugin only works with certain meshes like Plane and circle it does not work with cube, cone, cylinder, that is any of solid object.. I was always trying it with theses shapes and was not working. Is it default intended  behaviour?

Comment: F2 works with every mesh. However the thing is that due to thing which F2 does - creating a face with respect to existing faces, vertices and mouse posiiton - it does when there's possibility for that. Thus manifold meshes (cube, cone, cylinder) won't work with F2 as long as you don't create new [non-manifold](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/1245) details (extrude a single vertex etc.)