# How to make countour edges

Tags: modeling, edges

I have a shape and I want to offset or contour the edges as you can see in the image below. Is there any add-on to offset the edge or any other method?

[image: shape with outlines]

Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Your grease pencil lines aren't planar. Is this what you intend to do or do you just want to have concentric duplicates of the shape? This needs some clarification.

Comment: yes i want concentric duplicates of the shape from small to big

Answer (score 4):

As a lazy solution which also needs some clearing work, use [Offset Edges](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges) addon. See [how to install addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon) to access its functionality.

First, for it to work properly, apply scale for the object (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*) and remove doubles (<kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*).

With that, run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges* > *Offset* (or *Extrude*, depending on whether you want the extruded edges to be connected to original ones or not).
It won't work well in the corners because of big amount of vertices there. You might need to edit that by using e.g. *Vertex Slide* tool to grab vertices along the edges to get rid of distorted corners.

[image: screenshot of mesh with offsetted edges]

[image: screenshot of mesh with cleaned corners]

Repeat the same for yet one more concentric iteration.

This will be easier if you dissolve that big amount of vertices before using the addon with *Limited Dissolve* (not an option if those vertices are needed as details).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's only one "easy" and reliable method to achieve concentric copies in Blender. Depending on what you want to do with the shapes, there's still a little work ahead. Basically we "abuse" the Solidifiy Modifier to get the desired result.

1. Tab into Edit Mode, press <kbd>W</kbd> and select "Remove Doubles".
   Then extrude the shape on the Z-axis. The size doesn't matter, since
   we delete the upper loopcut later on, anyway.

   [image: prepare base mesh]
2. Tab into Object Mode and with your object selected,  go to
   "Properties - Modifiers" and add a Solidify Modifier. In the
   Modifier Settings, deselect "Fill Rim", then select "Even
   Thickness".

   [image: add modifier]
3. The distance between the two sides is controlled by the Thickness.
   Adjust it and then apply the Modifier (don't worry about the
   overlapping edges, we have to fix them manually in the next step).
   Then Tab into Edit Mode and delete the two upper rims.

   [image: adjust distance, apply Modifier and delete upper rims]
4. Now we have to fix the newly created shape by removing the
   overlapping edges (the following gif shows only one side due to the
   image size limit, but you'll get the picture).

   [image: fixing the shape]
5. Depending on what you want to do with the shapes (filling the rims
   with faces?) you need to recreate the deleted vertices in order to
   get a decent copy (again, the gif shows only one side).

   [image: add the missing vertices]
6. If you want to have a more even distribution of your vertices (this
   helps if you want to fill the rims with faces), you can fix that by
   using the Loop Tools add-on. Due to the shape of the object (and how
   accurate it should be), this should be done in several steps per
   rim.

   Select the straight parts of the rim, then hit <kbd>W</kbd>, select
   "LoopTools" and "Space". Repeat for the other parts. The curved part
   might work in one step. The difference on that part is most
   prominent.

   [image: distribute vertices evenly]

   Repeat this on both rims until all the vertices are distributed
   evenly.
7. When you're done, repeat the whole process from Step 1 on the newly
   created outer rim to create a third one.

Here's a .blend file with three rims, vertices evenly distributed:

[image]