# How to convert vertex group to sculpting mask?

Tags: sculpting, vertex-groups, masking

How to convert vertex group to mask in Sculpt mode ?

I take any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to achieve that with Dyntopo enabled and [Mask Tools](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?371584-Mask-Tools) addon installed (see [Installing an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon)) and activated.

With addon, in Sculpt mode press *Vertex Group To Mask* button on the *Toolshelf* > *Sculpt* rollout.

[image: GIF converting vertex group to mask]

Dyntopo allows that because the geometry needed for vertex group will be dynamically created while using Sculpt brush.
The Multires modifier isn't available for that unfortunately.