# Converting a vertex group into a sculpt mask

Tags: python

Is there an easy way to use a vertex group and convert it into a sculpting mask. I realize this question has been asked before and someone had created an add-on, which is outdated.

here is the link... [How to convert vertex group to sculpting mask?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67179/how-to-convert-vertex-group-to-sculpting-mask)

Perhaps a python script to do this?

This could be very useful in blender.

Comment: Please add link to _"asked before"_

Comment: I have added the link the the original question.