# How to batch import images as brush textures?

Tags: import, image, sculpting

I have a folder with some b&w images that I want to use as brushes textures while sculpting.
Is there a way to automatically load these images as brush textures, or do I have to do it one by one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an addon just for this, [Import BrushSet](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/BrushSet). You can download the addon from [here](https://developer.blender.org/T25702).

After you have it [installed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1689/2217), simply click on *File* > *Import* > *Brush Set*.
[image: import brush set]

You have to choose a folder (don't pick any images, just the folder) and the addon will import all the images in that folder and set them up as brush textures. (It would be a good idea to make a separate folder with only the images you want to import)

It's as simple as that.

Comment: Also another addon that is similar but supplies a way to determine the fiel location and also enables deleting any brush images not currently in use, clearing the cache is load_alphas at https://github.com/amb/blender-scripts/blob/master/load_alphas.py