# I am having troubles installing "space_view3d_turntable_y_up.py" Blender addon

Tags: add-on, installation

As shown in the link https://gist.github.com/rraallvv/5959426

How do I install this particular addon (space_view3d_turntable_y_up.py)?

Furthermore can this addon replace the y and the z axis?

Comment: Please elaborate on what issues you are having.  [Installing an addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon)

Comment: I ran the python script in the text editor, yet I am not noticing any difference. Is this addon broken or something? Also am I understanding correctly that this addon is supposed to swap the z and the y axis so that the y axis is pointing up?

Comment: The location suggests `'3d view > Ctrl + LMB-drag',`  ie hit control key while dragging with left mouse in the 3d view.