# How do I get the 'Fracture' panel to appear in the Toolshelf?

Tags: interface

What must I do to get the "fracture" panel to appear in the 3D View Toolshelf? I have download the "Blender fracture; version --> 2.79a".

I have made a picture of a Youtube video where I can see that they have the "fracture" panel (I have made a orange circle around the 'Fracture' panel):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, this addon is bundled with the Fracture Modifier Build, it should be inside the "fracture_extra" folder within the zip file which contains the build. ("fracture_helper.py") Alternatively you can separately download it here:

http://blenderphysics.com/fracturemodifier/

(Helper Addon)

The addon might also be updated separately from the build from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addon which one should [install](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon) separately.
Download it here:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Fracture

Comment: Please answer in English and edit your answer to explain how this link helps.