# How to center multiple objects automatically before exporting?

Tags: objects, export, transforms, .fbx

so I have a seemingly obvious question.

I am needing to export multiple meshes in the same scene one at a time, and as they are, the meshes are placed all over the space. It seems to me that I need to move each one to `(0, 0, 0)`, before I export them (as fbx) or else they import to Unity with the random location transforms. Is there some way that can automatically do this zeroing out process upon exporting? This way I won't have to move them one by one just before export.

This is an example of my scene :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default FBX or OBJ exporters won't allow you skip resetting object location if you want their origin point remain where it is once exported. However there are some addons which make this possible.

One of these addons is [Export FBX](https://github.com/CenekStrichel/CendaTools/wiki/Export-FBX) which is a part of [Cenda Tools](https://github.com/CenekStrichel/CendaTools/wiki). After [installing the addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon) open the Properties Editor > Scene tab > Export Settings rollout. There fill in the path where the file will be saved

As per [addon page](https://github.com/CenekStrichel/CendaTools/wiki/Export-FBX):

> Fill the export paths (it is saved with scene), select objects for export and click the Export button. *Backup* is doing a copy of the exported FBX.

[image]

Object can be exported from the 3D viewport as well:

[image]

Note that addon assumes file name is included in the export path, by default it is empty name with extension so make sure to change it.

Answer (score 5):

Select all your objects then Alt+G to Clear Location (set the location to 0;0;0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to keep the objects in their current positions within the blender scene but export them into Unity with 0;0;0, without moving them to the center in Blender. Was hoping there'd be some option upon export or something

Comment: I don't think such an option exists. Save the blend, export then reload the save ?

Comment: You can Hit Alt+G and Export and get back to the previous locations by 2 Undo actions (Ctrl+Z)

Comment: Blender should really have option to export with origin moved to 0,0,0 without actually changing it in the blender file. hotkeys are not a place for this really.