# trying to install add-on but not working

Tags: add-on, fspy

I recently found out about a program called Fspy. to use it with blender it requires an add-on. I tried installing the addon and blender said modules installed successfully, but I couldn't find the add-on in the preferences. I tried manually installing the add-on (by unzipping it and putting it in this file destination: **C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons**. I can see the folder in the destination but not n blender.

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you [activate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/installing-an-addon) it after installation?

Comment: Also be sure to download the correct version. It should be [fSpy-Blender-1.0.2.zip](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy-Blender/releases) and not the master file from Github